# Error when initializing array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am trying to initialize a simple array in java with 10 integers.
Problem is that, no matter what I do, the output always comes completely different from what it is supposed to be.
Example:

```
int[] example = new int[] { 2, 5, 7 };
System.out.println(example);
```

Result: [I@fd13b5

Another one:

```
int[] myList = {1,2,5,4,13,451,4};
System.out.println(myList);
```

Result:[I@7ffe01

Even if I do not assign anything to it:

```
int[] numberList = new int[10];
System.out.println(numberList);
```

Result: [I@1fae3c6

I really have no clue why it does this... Can someone please help?
I don't know if it matters but I am using Eclipse.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should print the array with

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList));
```

The default `toString()` implementation in `Object` class doesn't display the elements of the array.

Comment: This question has several duplicate answers already